# VBA debugging, object does not support this property

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, web-scraping

I am very new to VBA and stack overflow. I am developing a vba that takes first 5 URL links from a Chinese search engine, Baidu.com. But there are some mistakes that I could not solve after a day looking at it. Please give some help.

```
Sub GettingURL()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://baidu.com/s?wd=" & Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 2).Text
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4:  DoEvents:  Wend

        With .document.all.ires.getElementsByTagName("A")
            c = 3
            For u = 0 To Application.Min(8, .Length - 1) Step 2
                Sheets("Data").Cells(c, 1) = .Item(u).href
                c = c + 1
            Next
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for replying, this code works perfectly when I change the search engine to google instead (changing "https://baidu.com/s?wd=" to "www.google.co.in/search?q=". I am trying to get the first 5 urls from search engine after I search for a word.

Comment: for example, if I search for "red", it will return "https://www.red.com", "https://fanyi.baidu.com/?aldtype=85#en/zh/red", "https://cn.red.com", "https://music.163.com/#/search/m/?s=red&type=1&market=baiduqk" and "https://baike.baidu.com/item/red/4350191?fr=aladdin"

Comment: I can't match your exact links to the html I get perhaps due to my geographic location. Can you share the html of a couple of the elements you are targeting please? I can, for example get: https://www.red.com/ ;
fanyi.baidu.com ;
https://cn.red.com/ ;
music.163.com ;
baike.baidu.com/ ;  I can also get results that include strings like: http://fanyi.baidu.com/#en/zh/re

Comment: The green links, for example, can be selected with .document.querySelectorAll(".c-showurl")

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: thanks for replying, I do not need to get the exact links. I just need to get the first 5 links for any search after a random search.

Comment: the error line is With .document.all.ires.getElementsByTagName("A")

Comment: because .ires is not valid for this page.

Comment: If any 5 links then just use .document.getElementsByTagName("a") and loop the first 5 in the returned collection. but this does not return a valid selection you can use for the first 5 so there must be something else to make more targeted to certain links.

Comment: The links in green are valid and associated with search results... but you don't want those?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the html showing where the urls of interest (these 5) are coming from for "red"?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr;**

So, this was bugging me until....... I thought what if the links in the HTML end up appearing differently upon direction to the page.

So, whilst not technically the first 5 (as the page styling is not consistent for element number 5; it is missing an h3 tag), this appears to match your given list in the comments when you look at the final URL yielded.

---

**CSS selector combination:**

I use a CSS selector combination to target the page of `#content_left h3 [href]`. This looks for elements with an `href` attribute inside a parent `h3` element inside an element with id `content_left`.

This is what the CSS query matches look like for the search term `red`. (Sample provided)

[image]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the CSS selector combination via the `querySelectorAll` method of `document` , as you are expecting more than one matched element, which returns a static `nodeList`. You loop the `.Length` of the returned `nodeList` to access items by index.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GettingURL()
    Dim c As Long, u As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://baidu.com/s?wd=" & Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 2).Text
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4:  DoEvents:  Wend

        With .document.querySelectorAll("#content_left h3 [href]")
            c = 3
            For u = 0 To 4                       ' Application.Min(8, .Length - 1)
                Sheets("Data").Cells(c, 1) = .Item(u)
                c = c + 1
            Next
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Results:**

Comparing the retrieved URLs and what they finally appear as, if you enter them in the navigation bar, you get the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works perfectly now. I love this community!

Comment: is there any method to improve this code so that it will abstract every top 5 searches of every page of the search result?

Comment: @liuchao, accept the answer! it will add a green check to the answer, and when search, people that has similar doubt too, will look here first.